# Is there an option to not use Photos on macOS to maintain/sync iOS photos?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, photo-stream

I'm giving up. For over a year `Photos` on `macOS` says "*Preparing to import from ...*" in an infinite loop.

None of the [try-everything suggestions](https://appletoolbox.com/photos-preparing-to-import-from-iphone/) actually works. At most, putting the phone in Airplane mode succeeds one time in 3-4, and even then it works very briefly. Syncing with `Image Capture` rather than `Photos` works, but then `Photos` takes over and restarts the loop. I upgraded iOS and macOS to no avail.

I'd now like to use another mechanism. Manually using `AirDrop` for a few dozen photos/videos at a time is too tedious. It's also error-prone. I found (the hard way, of course) that dragging the photos from the `Downloads` folder to `Photos` adds the photos but the files must remain in `Downloads`. When you add a photo to `Photos`, `Photos` clearly does a hard link and not a soft link (as in `ln -s`).

I know that `Photos` is built into `macOS`, at least the recent releases, and that it's not possible to remove it. I'm not even sure where the `Photos.app` folder is. It's not under `/Applications`.

Is there an option to not use Photos on macOS to maintain/sync iOS photos? In other words, when I connect an iPhone to macOS using Thuderbolt, I'd like the `Photos` app to **not** launch. (Finding an app that syncs will be step #2; for now I'm asking about this step #1).

In case it's relevant, I've been upgrading macOS in-place since `Tiger`. That by itself is likely a bad idea, but given how opaque `iTunes`, `iPhotos` (previously), and now `Photos` are in maintaining their databases, it's not too clear how I can copy music + photos/videos following a clean install.

Comment: don't really have an answer here, but regarding your last thing, iTunes and Photos store their databases as folders on your computer that you can see in `~/Music` and `~/Pictures` - if you want to copy them just copy those folders to an external disk or from one partition to the new one.

Comment: @Ezekiel Have you successfully moved `~/Music` and `~/Pictures` to an alternative location, upgraded macOS, then moved them back, and found your music and your photos intact?

Comment: This seems to ask several things at once, making it hard to answer. How the auto-launch of Photos can be prevented is described in the answers to the question on top. Can you maybe post new, specific questions for the issues?

Comment: @Calaf Yes I have